# Using jQuery selectors to iterate through DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, css-selectors

Can someone tell me why this won't work?

```
var top = 0;
for (divToPosition in $('.positionableDiv')) {
   divToPosition.css('top',top+'px');
   top = top + 30;
}
```

Comment: What's it doing (or not doing)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The first reason would be the misuse of the `for` loop.

jQuery has an idiom for looping over selected elements..

```
var top = 0;
$('.positionableDiv').each(function() {
   $(this).css('top',top+'px');
   top = top + 30;
});
```

Please take a look at [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) for a better understanding of the way a for...in loop works in javascript, it does not enumerate in the same way as say .NET or Java.

From Article:

> Although it may be tempting to use this as a way to iterate over an Array, this is a bad idea.

Comment: thanks for pointing out my mis-use of javascript looping, you just saved me some hurt

Answer (score 6):

The correct way to iterate over a set of matched elements is with [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/), as other answers have mentioned. Attempting to use a `for..in` loop will iterate over the properties of the jQuery object, not the elements it matched.

To improve slightly on some of the other `.each` examples, you could omit the `top` variable to clean things up a little. The first parameter to `.each` is in the index of the element within the set of matched elements; you could achieve the same thing by multiplying it by 30 at each step. There is no incrementing and no `top` variable cluttering things up:

```
$('.positionableDiv').each(function(i) {
    $(this).css('top', (i * 30) + "px");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This would work:

```
var top = 0;
for (var pdiv in $('.positionableDiv').get()) {
   $(pdiv).css('top', top + 'px');
   top = top + 30;
}
```

Basically, you use `get()` to retrieve the array of elements.

Answer (score 2):

The "for (var key in obj)" is suitable for iterating the members of an object. It works for native JavaScript arrays as long as their prototype is not extended. A jQuery object may look as a native JavaScript array but it is not hence "for ( in )" fails.

You can use [.each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate over a jQuery object:
var top = 0;

```
$('.positionableDiv').each(function() {
     $(this).css('top', top);
     top += 30;
});
```

Comment: Moreover, even if it was an Array you wouldn't want to be using for-in, as @Quintin points out... and I just found out

Answer (score 1):

The $('.positionableDiv') in your statement is a jQuery object with a great many properties.  What you want is to iterate through the matched elements which is not done that way.

Try:

```
var top = 0;
$('.positionableDiv').css('top', function(index, value) {
    var cTop = top;
    top = top + 30;
    return cTop + 'px';
});
```

Comment: As Quintin states, the use of the .each() method is a more general way of iterating over a collection of matched elements.  The .css() method provides a way to process using a callback function directly, so I demonstrated that as above.  Possibly slightly less clear in this case, due to the variable in play being set after the value needing to be returned.

Comment: I appreciate the alternative you provided, always good to know all options- Thanks

Comment: @Yarin Which method is the more appropriate depends upon the situation at hand.  jQuery excels at making code terse and clear, so it is nice to see a number of similar but alternate methods proposed.